# IntelliJ "Initialization failed for 'https://start.spring.io' Please check URL, network and proxy settings"

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

Today when using IntelliJ (MacOS) & Spring Boot to create  a new project, I started seeing this error:

"
Initialization failed for 'https://start.spring.io' Please check URL, network and proxy settings

Error Message:
Error parsing JSON response
"

My home network has no HTTP proxy settings, just plain vanilla Internet.
IntelliJ / Preferences / System Settings / HTTP Proxy / Check Network Settings: says network connection is ok. And this same setup worked here 2 days ago.

Browser connection to https://start.spring.io also works.

I tried Googling this issue, but mostly found HTTP Proxy setting issues that I don't have (I am typing this w/o HTTP Proxy settings in browser :-)).

Maybe this is just a transient issue with start.spring.io? or ... ?
Anyways confusing.

Comment: Yep, it is happening for me too.

Comment: The problem seems to be at the end of spring.io. I've had a look at what Fiddler says, and the response from spring.io is `<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Spring Initializr is broken for both IntelliJ IDEA and Spring Tools Suite, I reported this to the initialzr project:

https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/issues/267

Comment: Issue resolved, I can create projects by using IntelliJ and STS. The spring team is improving their codebase and created an issue to IntelliJ IDEA [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159177).

Answer (score 5):

- If your r able to open the same url in your browser then the issue is with the `proxy settings` on the `IDE`.
- In that case, we can define the existing browser proxy settings to the intelliJ as below-
- On the IDE, `Open --> File -> Settings -> Appearance and Behavior ->System Settings -> HTTP Proxy --> Select Auto-detect proxy settings` and set the `Automatic proxy configuration URL`.
- Then we can able to connect to spring initializer through `intelliJ IDE`

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I had my VPN settings saved in the IDE from a while back.

Answer (score 4):

try to use '**http**://start.spring.io' instead of '**https**://start.spring.io'.
it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with "could not connect to server " by changing the name of the artifact, previously the name had an umlaut